# PHP upload image error wrong extension

Tags: php, image, file, upload

I am using this code trying to upload images to the server. I am selecting JPG images. For some reason Im getting an error showing the extension is invalid or wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $currentDir = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = "/tutorials/";

    $errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

    $fileExtensions = ['JPG','jpeg','jpg','png']; // Get all the file 
    extensions

    $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

    $uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
            $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a 
      JPEG or PNG file";
        }

        if ($fileSize > 5000000) {
            $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be 
         less than or equal to 2MB";
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

            if ($didUpload) {
                echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been 
          uploaded";
            } else {
                echo "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the 
        admin";
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the php error log yet?

Comment: There does no seem to be much point putting an upper case extension name in the array if you are doing a strtolower on the incoming extension

Comment: what's the exact output of $fileExtension ?

Comment: 5000000 !== 2MB

Comment: Riggs - Im aware of the 5000000....still need to change that...but that is not causing the problem. I will looking into the suggestions. Thanks

Comment: When I echo both $fileName or $fileExtension nothing shows